# .NET Core daignostics for method entry exit and parameter values

Tags: .net-core

Does there exist a .NET Core utility which would log method entry exit and parameter values for a running process? For example:

[9/3/19 17:43:07:416 CEST] 00000484 samples.web.rest.BusinessLogicService > getBusinessObject ENTRY

[9/3/19 17:43:07:517 CEST] 00000484 samples.web.rest.BusinessLogicService < getBusinessObject RETURN {"firstName":"Test","lastName":"Object"}

So some sort of a trace, but without having to design and code for tracing or use AOP libraries.

Comment: You'd like something that logs every method in your application, both entry (start) and returning (exit), without having to instrument the code yourself (adding extra lines to your code), did I understand that correctly?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.